# Electron affinity

Tags: electrons, energy, noble-gases

Concerning the liberation of energy when an atom that is close to the configuration of a noble gas:

Where does the energy dissipated from an atom upon receiving an electron come from?

Answer (score 2):

Well everything in nature wants to or tries to attain a configuration where it is at its lowest energy.
When an atom receives an electron and completes its octet it becomes more stable or in other words we can say that it has acquired a stable configuration.
The energy released was always present in the species before bonding took place.

Comment: In which form is that energy present?

Comment: in the form of potential energy.breaking a bond is endothermic.
to break a bond you need to provide energy and that energy is stored as potential energy.when that species reacts to form a bond then that energy is released that is we say that bond making is exothermic

Answer (score 1):

The electron is attracted to the nucleus but repelled by other electrons.  In some atoms, adding an electron is an exothermic process because the potential energy of the lone electron and the atom apart are converted to kinetic energy.  In these cases the attraction of the nucleus overcomes the repulsion of the electrons.  Not all octet forming is exothermic.  The second electron affinity of oxygen is endothermic for example.