# Why do objects gain electrons?

Tags: electrons, atoms, protons, atomic-structure

I have read that objects gain electrons to become negatively charged and also that they lose electrons to become positively charged. I have also read that same charges repel each other and non-same charges attract each other. My question is how can objects gain electrons when the electrons should repel each  other.

For example: an element has 17 electrons, so its electronic configuration will be:

```
K L M
2 8 7
```

So, it will gain 1 electron. But how can this happen? I mean, shouldn't the electrons repel each other? Moreover, if it gains an electron how will it become stable? I mean I agree that there will be 18 electrons but to become stable shouldn't there be 18 protons? So from where will the extra proton come from?

Comment: The extra proton will not come at all. Then again, in the middle there is a nucleus with 17 protons, and it attracts the extra electron with the same force as the existing 17 electrons repel it, or even a bit stronger.

Comment: but don't the 17 protons cancel out the 17 electrons?? So what attracts the extra electron??

Comment: @ProNeon they don't cancel out

Comment: aren't electrons and protons opposite of each other??Doesn't electrons carry -1 charge and protons carry +1 charge?? So don't they cancel each other??

Comment: They would, if they all were located precisely at one point, which they aren't.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Does that mean the protons and electrons have different charges?? I mean does that mean protons have more than +1 charge and neutrons have less than -1 charge??

Comment: No, they have exactly opposite charges.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So what does exactly causes the attraction??The position??Or something else??And why does position matter??Aren't the electrons revolving around fixed orbits and aren't the protons present in the nucleus??

Comment: I guess you know that the electrostatic force depends not only on the charge, but also on the distance, right?

Comment: A clear answer would have the shape and size of a textbook on quantum mechanics. Electrons do not revolve, nor do they really have a position.

Comment: or maybe https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/electron-affinity would be a better dupe

Comment: @Mithoron I fail to see how either of the linked questions answers the OP's question: "shouldn't the electrons repel each other?" Do you mind explaining? Thank you.